# Applying to an Econ PhD program as a software engineer?

Tags: graduate-admissions

I'm in a similar situation as this poster: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/16428/career-change-to-economics-from-software-engineering , but it doesn't look like anyone answered about grad school admissions there. I have math and CS degrees from a top school, and if I could go back I would have taken classes and research in economics, but since I've already graduated and been working for 2 years, I feel like I've missed that opportunity. I'm self-studying economics right now, but what are some ways I could get experience that would be good for a grad school application?

I'm very interested in development economics, public policy, health economics, and behavioral economics and I know what my dream research groups and research directions are, if I can get the right skills/credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not in economics

You might consider applying for a MS degree first. I don't know about economics, but I know that in my field at my university, we are a little more selective about Ph.D. admissions versus MS admissions, having something like twice as many MS candidates as Ph.D. candidates. If you otherwise had good GPA and good test scores, you can probably get into an MS degree at a decent school, although maybe not your dream school.  If you can exceed at the MS degree, get a publication or two and network at a few conferences, then you've got a much better shot at a top ranked Ph. D. program.

Comment: Economist here: this makes sense. Alternatively, try to work as an RA as a "pre-doc" -- you will be in high demand if you are a great programmer in the right languages (probably R and Stata and understand the concepts of causal inference).

Answer (score 0):

Not in economics either (but I have a sibling who has a PhD in it, and that basically informs my perspective)

While having formal credentials is always helpful, I think you might be OK as long as your applications (A) prove that you have a solid base in economics (even if it's self-taught), (B) demonstrate that you have some sense of direction in terms of what you want to research, (C) show how your existing credentials and work experience all translate into transferable knowledge/skills that are applicable to your area of interest in economics. I think having a background in math and computer science is a *huge* asset -- you probably have much of the quantitative/programming/statistics skills that are necessary for advanced studies in econ. I remember when my sister was doing her PhD, she regretted not having a stronger math background, and also over the years she needed to learn different programs like SAS, Stata, and R (which also remain relevant in her current line of work).

EDIT: I also want to add that I actually didn't have a formal degree in my area of study when I first applied to MA programs. That said, one thing I did - in addition to just teaching myself as much as possible - was informally auditing classes. It might be worth looking into some local universities and seeing if you can informally/unofficially sit in on a class or two. A lot of professors might be strict about this (and some universities might have specific policies re: non-students attending classes), so you might need to officially audit. You'd have to pay for it, but on the upside, you'd have an official record of it.

Comment: I agree with this as well - you could take 1 or 2 courses to show your seriousness. In addition, they would help you get a pre-doc position if you go that route. Pre-docs can really help you get into top programs in Econ because they usually involve working with a known professor who can give a great letter.